# Apache Flink limit data being processed

Tags: java, streaming, apache-flink

I am looking for an option wherein I can limit the amount of data that is being currently processed.

Use case: I am reading from a Kafka data stream and processing that data, and I want to limit the number of messages that are in-flight. The reason for doing this is the throughput of the third-party application.
Generally it's not an issue, but in the scenarios of backpressure, there are frequent failures and application restarts because of these failures.

Comment: How are you connecting from Flink to this third party application?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027848/2000823 for an example that uses rate limiting, or use https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/ and set the capacity appropriately.

Comment: Its an rest service call to the third party app

Answer (score 1):

Some tools available for this are:

1. Limit the parallelism.
2. Use Flink's [async i/o operator](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/) to handle the connection to the 3rd party API, and set its capacity (number of in-flight requests) accordingly. This will ultimately backpressure the sources.
3. Apply rate-limiting to the sources. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65232295/2000823 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027848/2000823 for more on that topic.