# Is there anyway to combine KafkaSource and ThrottledIterator in Flink 1.15?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

There are many old topics about rate limiting / throttling Kafka consumer

- [How to use Ratelimiter on flink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227642/how-to-use-ratelimiter-on-flink/65232295)
- [Dynamically throttle flink kafka sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228544/dynamically-throttle-flink-kafka-sources)
- etc.

But none of them can be used in case 1.15:

- `KafkaFetcher` does not expose `emitRecord`

  - [Now it resides](https://whereismyanswer.com/questions/68015264/flink-kafka-custom-consumer-for-rate-limit) inside the `KafkaRecordEmitter`
- `FlinkKafkaConsumer` is [deprecated](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#kafka-sourcefunction)

  - `KafkaSource` is the preferred approach
- `KafkaSource` [explicitly creates](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/010891a15bc34044ae599c1cd8ed09ff0a1da98f/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/source/KafkaSource.java#L158) a `KafkaRecordEmitter` inside it's `createReader`

So, my question is that is there anyway to combine [`ThrottledIterator`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/utils/ThrottledIterator.html) with `KafkaSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't applying rate limiting in the main processing thread, as this can/will block checkpointing. What you should do instead is apply rate limiting in a deserialization schema.

You can set up a rate limiter in the deserialization schema's `open` method and acquire it in the `deserialize` method. (But I would use a Guava RateLimiter rather than a throttled iterator for this.)

Comment: So are you suggesting to use the ratelimiter in our derived class of `AbstractDeserializationSchema`?

Comment: [RateLimiter is marked unstable with @Beta](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/5959). As I can see [resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j#ratelimiter) is recommended approach instead.